# Admob " Reward video failed to load."

Tags: xcode, admob, swift4, rewardedvideoad

Iv'e been stuck on this for ages now, and I'm totally stumped with what to do.

When I call for a rewarded video ad within my ios app, it says in the console " Reward video failed to load.". What's confusing is that when I substitute in the admob test ad unit ID, the test ads load up perfectly fine.

Then confusingly when I run the test ads on a real device, I get this warning..
" Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target. "

I'm just unsure if it is a google admob account issue, or an Xcode issue, or an sdk issue, or even a mediation issue I have no idea.

I've already looked over a few threads but most of them don't help me out at all. This is also on a fresh admob account, only a day old. 
If there's anyone who has seen this issues before I'd love your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your "limit ad tracking" is on (Settings > Privacy > Advertising). Once I think I had this problem and turning it off worked for me.

Comment: Hey I’m running an iPhone 7 Plus, I’ll give it a go.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, I was also more focused on getting the real ad unit ID working on the simulator. Thanks for your help anyways